# Github actions workflow cannot checkout a public repo

Tags: reactjs, github-actions

Today when I run the github actions https://github.com/RedDwarfTech/texhub-web workflow with my public repo, shows error:

```
Run git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf ssh://git@github

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 763ms

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
Packages: +1797
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 32, added 27
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 75, added 73
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 132, added 131
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 189, added 189
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 244, added 243
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 300, added 299
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 362, added 362
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 421, added 421
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 483, added 483
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 542, added 543
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 592, added 593
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 649, added 650
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 705, added 706
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 760, added 761
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 818, added 819
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 874, added 875
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 924, added 925
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 971, added 972
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1017, added 1018
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1073, added 1074
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1124, added 1124
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1182, added 1182
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1241, added 1242
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1299, added 1300
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1359, added 1360
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1418, added 1419
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1481, added 1482
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1542, added 1543
Progress: resolved 1797, reused 0, downloaded 1599, added 1600
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 128: git fetch --depth 1 origin baf7fecd350398b32e523f14bc4f4536f9bc6f82
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

pnpm: Command failed with exit code 128: git fetch --depth 1 origin baf7fecd350398b32e523f14bc4f4536f9bc6f82
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
    at makeError (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:24966:17)
    at handlePromise (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:25537:33)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async gitFetcher (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:110929:11)
    at async fetcher (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:123551:16)
    at async run (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:123017:23)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

the workflow works fine for months, why suddenly shows this error? this is the github actions workflow file:

```yaml
name: tex-web-pro

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Build React App
        run: |
          npm install -g pnpm 
          pnpm install
          pnpm run build
        env:
          CI: false

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build image push to aliyun
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          tags: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}/reddwarf-pro/texhub-web:${{ github.sha }} 
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
          file: Dockerfile
          push: true
    
       # https://github.com/steebchen/kubectl
      - name: deploy to cluster
        uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
        with: # defaults to latest kubectl binary version
          config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
          command: set image --record deployment/texhub-web texhub-web=registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/texhub-web:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro

      - name: verify deployment
        uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
        with:
          config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
          version: v1.21.0 # specify kubectl binary version explicitly
          command: rollout status deployment/texhub-web -n reddwarf-pro
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? I found when fetch this dependencies https://github.com/RedDwarfTech/y-websocket facing this error, the dependencies defined in `package.json` look like this:

```
"y-websocket": "github:RedDwarfTech/y-websocket#baf7fecd350398b32e523f14bc4f4536f9bc6f82"
```

this repo is public, why still facing this issue?

Comment: Can you try removing that git config step? I don't think that's needed in actions.

Comment: why this config step suddenly not work?

Comment: I have tried to remove the git config step but still could not fixed this issue.

Comment: Regenerate lockfile maybe? I'm not sure why it broke. Maybe something changed between pnpm minor (8.14 was released yesterday)? (PS: It is recommended to use pnpm/action-setup and specify packageManager field in your package.json. That will lock the pnpm version.)

Comment: I found when I remove the lockfile this error will disappear, but when I run the github action in the furture, this error will happen again. I have tried to upgrade the pnpm version to `8.15.1`. what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe create an issue on the pnpm repo with a minimal example they can reproduce by just cloning/forking your repo?

Answer (score -1):

You might have removed the github username and password or the access key is not authorized anymore.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: this is a public github repo that did not need any access key.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the 2 steps you are doing in order to be able to reproduce this? I think the git config and the npm install are the relevant steps maybe.